# NSIS - How to override "un.onInit" callback

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I am new in NSIS scripting, and I want to add a prompt message before the default uninstall window pop up. And if they click Proceed, uninstalling will continue by showing the default uninstall window, but if they click Cancel, uninstalling will stop and won't delete any application files.

Thank you.

I tried this script:

```
Function un.onInit

  MessageBox MB_YESNO "This will uninstall. Continue?"

FunctionEnd
```

But I'm getting an error when running electron-builder:

```
Error: Function named "un.onInit" already exists.
!include: error in script: "uninstaller.nsh" on line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Electron is already using that callback for its own purpose but it does provide the option of a macro you can use. See the custom script section in [their documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html#custom-nsis-script).

In the custom .nsh, simply add the macro:

```
!macro customUnInit
MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "Are you sure you want to uninstall $(^Name)?" IDYES +2
  Quit
!macroend
```